# Go to definition for F# library

Tags: visual-studio, f#, go-to-definition

It is probably a trivial question. But how can I link the F# source code to the Visual Studio so that "Go to definition" would work for F# functions (such as Seq.iter etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to grab the [F# source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp), build Fsharp.Core.dll, and then link against the version of Fsharp.Core.dll that you just built. This would give you the ability to debug into F# library source code just like any other library assembly for which you have home-built source code.

Comment: That sounds too complicated. But thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: I don't think this would enable "Go to definition," since it _just doesn't work_ for F#, but being able to step into the code when debugging is nice.